# How can i refund 0.017eth from fail confirmed transaction (ropsten)

Tags: gas

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xf0cc02d3fc8f53ecf90690757fafef646431996a

this example with out of gas. Create new transaction with nonce 5 not work, because tx is confirmed.
How can i return 0.017 eth from fail transaction

Comment: I think that ETH send was canceled and burn only eth for gas transaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you send ETH and your transaction fails you only loose the gas paid.

Answer (score 1):

Your transaction failed, because it ran out of gas. Whenever a transaction runs out of gas or fails for other reasons (e.g. a smart contract that reverts), the Ether sent in the transaction is returned. You only pay the gas used by the transaction, which is `Gas price * Gas limit`.

You can read more about gas [here](https://support.mycrypto.com/general-knowledge/ethereum-blockchain/what-is-gas).